# Matter.Constraints: BodyB property remains undefined

Tags: javascript, matter.js

I'm using matter.js and trying to add an object (candy) with a Matter.Body to options.bodyB. 
The error logs show that candy exists, has a body, and yet bodyB is undefined.[image]

[image]

Here is the actual Candy class. [image]

And here is where I actually pass the Candy to the Rope in the main class.
[image]

Comment: instead of just `bodyB` would it be `options.bodyB` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put:

```
console.log(options.bodyB);
```

instead of:

```
console.log(bodyB);
```

Comment: I mean it didn't work even without the logs... but now it does. So thank you, it seems I unknowingly fixed it while debugging, and now it was only the logs that caused an error.